# unify two rows of a dataframe in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame with the same records except the amount field and what I want is to unify it in a single row, and the amount fields that have the sum of both amounts. 
As I would do it? In scala.

```
I get the dataframe from a database:

val my_table = spark.read.table("table.myTable")
val df = my_table
.filter(col("ID")==="10") and
.filter(col("CENT")==="20") and
.filter(col("PROD")=== "122") and
.filter(col("CONTR").isin("0004", "0005", "0006"))).select(
"ID", "CENT", "PROD", "CONTR", "COD", "DATE", "AMOUNT").distinct()

df.show()


---------+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
ID       | CENT   | PROD         |CONTR       |COD          | DATE      | Amount |    
---------+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
10       |20      |122           |0004        |COD1         |2006-11-04 | 150.0  |
10       |20      |122           |0004        |COD1         |2006-11-04 | 300.0  |
10       |20      |122           |0005        |COD2         |2012-10-17 | 100.0  |
10       |20      |122           |0006        |COD3         |2015-12-05 | 500.0  |
---------+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+

Expected:

---------+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
ID       | CENT   | PROD         |CONTR       |COD          | DATE      | Amount |    
---------+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
10       |20      |122           |0004        |COD1         |2006-11-04 | 450.0  |
10       |20      |122           |0005        |COD2         |2012-10-17 | 100.0  |
10       |20      |122           |0006        |COD3         |2015-12-05 | 500.0  |
---------+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: I think you should include that DataFrame as text in your question, so it is more accessible to everyone.

Comment: It is already included

Comment: it seems you are looking for groupBy my multiple fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code groups the on all the column except `amount` and run `sum` aggregation on `amount` column and orders it by `cod`

```
object GroupBy {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = List(Bean3(10,20,122,"0004","COD1","2006-11-04",150.0),
      Bean3(10,20,122,"0004","COD1","2006-11-04",300.0),
      Bean3(10,20,122,"0005","COD2","2012-10-17",100.0),
      Bean3(10,20,122,"0006","COD3","2015-12-05",500.0)
    ).toDF
    val groupByCol = df.columns.diff(Array("id", "amount"))
    df.groupBy("id",groupByCol: _*).sum("amount")
      .withColumnRenamed("sum(amount)","amount")
      .orderBy("cod")
      .show()
  }

}

case class Bean3(id : Int,cent : Int,prod: Int,contr : String,cod : String,date : String,amount : Double)


+---+----+----+-----+----+----------+------+
| id|cent|prod|contr| cod|      date|amount|
+---+----+----+-----+----+----------+------+
| 10|  20| 122| 0004|COD1|2006-11-04| 450.0|
| 10|  20| 122| 0005|COD2|2012-10-17| 100.0|
| 10|  20| 122| 0006|COD3|2015-12-05| 500.0|
+---+----+----+-----+----+----------+------+
```

Comment: I want to do it with scala spark, the dataframe I take it from a database and I make a filter so that it returns those fields. the dataframe it gives me is the one in the attached image, what I want is to unify two rows in a single row by adding the amount. I have applied part of your code and it does not return what I expected.